# Why can I print structures inside function but not outside?

Tags: c++

Im working on this for a week, but still cant find the solution, when I print the elements of structure person inside the function "LoadPerson" it cout it ok, but when I try it inside main, it mess. I know there must be some problem with how the elements got stored, but I have no idea what is wrong.Thank you for any help in advance

PS: the text file contains just lines in patter Name;Surname;Age

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct TOsoba {
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int age;
};
void LoadPerson(FILE* file, TOsoba person)
{
    char str[20];
    char tempAge[5];
    fgets(str, 20, file);
    char *token1, *next_token1;
    token1 = strtok_s(str, ";", &next_token1);
    int order_in_lane = 0;
    while (token1 != NULL)
    {
        if (order_in_lane == 0)
        {
            memcpy(person.name, token1, strlen(token1) + 1);
            //cout << person.name << endl;
            token1 = strtok_s(NULL, ";", &next_token1);
        }
        else if (order_in_lane == 1)
        {
            memcpy(person.surname, token1, strlen(token1) + 1);
            //cout << person.surname << endl;
            token1 = strtok_s(NULL, ";", &next_token1);
        }
        else if (order_in_lane == 2)
        {
            memcpy(tempAge, token1, strlen(token1) + 1);
            person.age = atoi(tempAge);
            //cout << person.age << endl;
            token1 = strtok_s(NULL, ";", &next_token1);
        }
        order_in_lane++;
    }
}
int LoadManyHuman(TOsoba osoby[], const char* jmeno_souboru)
{
    FILE* file;
    int pocet = 0;
    fopen_s(&file, jmeno_souboru, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return (-1);
    }
    while (!feof(file)) {
        LoadPerson(file, osoby[pocet]);
        pocet++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return (pocet);
}
void OutputHumans(TOsoba persons[], int amount)
{
    // vypise osoby - prijmeni jmeno Vek
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        cout << persons[amount].name;
        cout << persons[amount].surname;
        cout << persons[amount].age << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    TOsoba ManyHumans[50];
    int pocet_osob = LoadManyHuman(ManyHumans, "osoby.txt");
    OutputHumans(ManyHumans, pocet_osob);
}
```

Comment: `void LoadPerson(FILE* file, TOsoba person)` should be `void LoadPerson(FILE* file, TOsoba & person)`

Comment: There should be a duplicate explaining what pass by reference is and why you want to use it over pass by value.

Answer (score 1):

In LoadPerson you pass a value :

```
void LoadPerson(FILE* file, TOsoba person)
```

So you can not modify its contents. You must have a pointer to a TOsoba to be able to modify it.

```
void LoadPerson(FILE* file, TOsoba *person)
```

Or by reference (thanks to @Thomas Matthews

```
void LoadPerson(FILE* file, TOsoba &person)
```

Then change other parts of code according to this.

Comment: Since this is C++, prefer passing by reference instead of pointers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why is it preferable to pass by pointer in c++?

Comment: It is **not** preferable to pass by pointer in **C++**.  Pointers, in both C and and C++, can point to *anywhere*, including invalid addresses.  Dereferencing an invalid pointer causes *Undefined Behavior*.  With a reference, the compiler ensures that the reference refers to an existing object.  Also, there is no deferencing a reference, you access it like a regular variable.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the persons using `amount` as index. Try this instead:

```
void OutputHumans(TOsoba persons[], int amount)
{
    // vypise osoby - prijmeni jmeno Vek
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        cout << persons[i].name;
        cout << persons[i].surname;
        cout << persons[i].age << endl;
    }
}
```